# Potential concerns or gains from buying and hosting content on a domain that has been redirecting for 17 years?

Tags: seo, domains, migration

A client of mine bought a domain that apparently sounds more attractive and intend to migrate their main website to it.

Besides from the regular domain migration concerns, should I also be concerned that this new domain never hosted any content, has 0 traffic over the years, and probably has been redirecting this whole time.

How would Google look into that scenario for this potential migration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You really have nothing to worry about in this case. Google understands that domains are bought, sold, and reused all the time.

It's not an issue that the domain hasn't hosted content before and has zero traffic, in fact it makes the migration simpler not having to worry about whether you want to try to meaningfully capture incoming traffic to the old site's URL structure.

When Google crawls the domain and realizes that it is no longer redirecting, they will index it as normal. You should be able to do this migration in exactly the same way as if you purchased a pristine, new domain.